# Where can I see a list of GitHub's newest repositories?

Tags: github

I'm interested to see what other people publish on GitHub. From personal experience, I know how valuable the first few watchers of a new project can be.

However, I can't seem to find a way to actually discover new repositories on GitHub. Here's what I've tried:

- `https://github.com/trending` - Shows "trending" repositories; not what I want.
- `https://github.com/topics/TAG?o=desc&s=updated` - Show a list of repositories tagged with `TAG`, sorted by "recently updated". Closer, but still not what I want.

Where can I find a list of *recently created* GitHub repositories?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use GitHub's [List public events](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#list-public-events) API endpoint:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl -sH "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/events |\
jq -rc '.[] | select(.type == "CreateEvent") | ("https://github.com/" + .repo.name)'
```

Example output:

```
$ ./gittok.sh
https://github.com/AriefAbdullah/3rd-assignment
https://github.com/geometricpanda/geometricpanda
https://github.com/kamalarieff/portfolio
https://github.com/g1nus/Twapp
```